# Scroll to top of element when fixed html,body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been searching around and cannot seem to find an answer.

When making an app that has a fixed `html` and `body` but a scrollable `div`:

```css
html, body { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; overflow: hidden; }
.inside { height: calc( 100vh - 8em ); overflow-y: scroll; }
```

When I am trying to scroll to the top of a `div` that outputs a response message, it seems to only move up ~200px but not all the way to the top:

[image]

So to explain the GIF above, when the user scrolls to the bottom, and submits the form it only moves up a little bit of the form. I then scrolled to the top manually to show the `#response` div (green bar). When the GIF refreshes, you can see it just ends on the initial nudge up a little.

My jQuery from the ajax is:

```
$( ".inside" ).animate({
    scrollTop: $( "#response" ).top
}, "slow" );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I have had success is instead of having `$( ".inside" ).animate({` is to have `$( "*" ).animate({`